# javascript/xml dom appendChild not showing updates in xml file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a html/javascript file where on clicking submit js function is called for creating new element and appending it in xml file. somehow when I open the xml file, there are no updates. I am new to XML DOM and I tried reading several answers relevant to this but none seem to fit my problem exactly. here are the codes. (index.html and customers.xml)
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign up or Login</title>
<style>
input
{
    width:auto;
}
</style>
<script>
    function updateCustomers()
    {
        var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(this.readyState==4 && this.status ==200)
            {
                xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
                newElement = xmlDoc.createElement("customer");
                x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("myShop")[0];
                x.appendChild(newElement);
                xlen=x.childNodes.length;
                window.alert("xlen is "+ xlen);
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "customers.xml", true);
        xhttp.send(null);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:9em 0 0 0;">
<p style="padding:1em;border:4px solid #5C246E;border-radius:0.5em;width:20%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#EED2EE, #DB70DB);">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME" /><br><br>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" /><br><br>
<input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="CHOOSE A PASSWORD" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGN UP" onclick="updateCustomers()"/>
</p>
<br><br><br><br>
<a href="login.html" style="color:#000;font-weight:bold;background-color:#d3d3d3;border:3px solid #d3d3d3;text-decoration:none;margin:0 0 0 40em;padding:1em;">LOGIN</a>
</body>
</html>
```

customer.xml:

```
<myShop>
</myShop>
```

I expect to see customer tag as child of myShop. Is that not possible at all? Thank you in advance

Comment: JavaScript does not update a file.... Or are you saying you keep getting the old file? If that is the case , cache busting is needed.

Comment: How do I update the xml file? I don't see a new tag <customer> in customers.xml after executing index.html in browser.

Comment: Do you think that you can update the .xml file on the server from the client? You can not do it. To make a permanent change to the file, you would need to have a serverside portion of your application.

Comment: Alright. So I must use say, Java class or JSP?  I thought XML DOM is supposed to allow modifications to xml file when used. Where does appendChild add the tag here then? just on client side for the sake of it? Thanks!

Comment: It is modifying the file in memory in the browser. It has nothing to do with the file on the server.

Comment: Use formdata to send modified file to server.On server save this file